# How to do email address validation using Javascript (without JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I'm trying to do an email address validation for an input text field, however, it must only submit if the entry is not null and has the @ char in it

Example 1 is the one that works, however, it excludes the need for the @ char

```
function emailvalidation() {
var x=document.forms["input"]["email"].value;

if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("Input email address, please!");
return false
}
```

Example 2 which does not work, but is how I imagine it would be written

```
    function emailvalidation() {
var x=document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
var email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (x<>null || x<>"" && x.value.match(email)) {
    alert("Input email address, please!");
return true
} else {
    alert("Input email address, please!");
return false
}
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you though, preferably without JQuery! Thanks!

Comment: What is the does "not work" means? Do you get false positives?

Comment: you can validate a valid email use regex. you can reference this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: If you only want the `@` sign why not use `x.indexOf('@') != -1`? Your second function should probably have `x.match(email)` instead of `x.value.match(email)` since `x` already IS the `value`.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you have examples that fail the second example? Have you tried replacing `<>` with `!==`? Works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe0a57n6/2/). You'll want to change the || to an && too.  I had to remove the `.value` from `x.value.match()` as I'm using a string in place of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Another email validation.

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of logical problems in your solution.
Firstly, the condition is that x is not null **and** x is not an empty string **and** x matches the pattern.
Secondly, `<>` is the wrong comparator for javascript; use `!=` or `!==`.
Thirdly, as pointed out by [putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539720/putvande) x is already the element's value, so `x.value.match()` is probably causing you issues.

```
function emailvalidation() {
  var x = document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
  var email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

  if (x !== null && x !== "" && x.match(email)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Input email address, please!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wrote my own comment as I got this one, thank you very much for it though, you've taught me a great deal! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for this! The solution was a mixture of all of the answers! Though, here is the final solution! Needed a new reg expression and !==

Thank you all though, from a JS beginner, it is really appreciated

```
function emailvalidation() {

var x=document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
var email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (x !== null && x !== "" && x.match(email)) {
return true
} else {
    alert("Input email address, please!");
return false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first script and requirements, one solution without regex, and one with.

Note that a text-inputfield only returns strings. 
Email-addresses must have something before the `@`, so we check if an `@` appears after the first character (using `indexOf` we don't require a regex). Also, if we have found the `@` that means the string was not empty!!
If the `@` is at the same position as the last `@` and this position is smaller then the total string-length, this gives us a `true` or `false` value, which we can instantly `return`.
If none of the three conditions is met, then we `alert` our error-message. `alert` returns `undefined` (which in itself coerces to `false` in javascript, but) which we force to a boolean `false` using *double not* `!!` and `return` that value.

The second example follows the same logic, but uses a regex.

```js
function emailvalidation(){ //without regex
  var s=document.forms.input.email.value
  ,   x=s.indexOf('@');
  return( x>0 && x===(x=s.lastIndexOf('@')) && x<s.length-1
        ) || !!alert("Input email address, please!");
}

function emailvalidation(){ //with regex
  return /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/.test(document.forms.input.email.value) || !!alert("Input email address, please!");
}
```

```html
<form name="input">
  <input name="email" type="text" />
</form>
<button onclick="alert(emailvalidation())">test</button>
```

Final note, *it's good that you are liberal in accepting email-addresses*, since trying to do a good job in regex is long and difficult, see for example this regex: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html
There is simply no 100% reliable way of confirming a valid email address other than sending an email to user and and waiting for a response. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation
*If* you *do* try to regex 'valid email-addresses' then inform your employer that *you are* going to cost him *business/clients/cash*!!!